# MVC 4 on windows 8 upgrade could not load type error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I have vs 2010 and 2012 ultimate on a windows 8 box, that used to be a win 7 box but got upgraded. When i try make any asp.net mvc 4 application in either 2010 or 2012 i get

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

when trying to load the application and make a request to the index on the home controller.

The System.Web.Http dll being referenced is:

```
C:\src\web\MvcApplication6\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll
```

so its coming from the mvc nuget package. What on earth is going on here :(

Comment: is it using out of the box routes, or did you change the routes?

Comment: Havent touched a thing, i literally only create the project type and f5 it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You - most likely - have conflicting versions of MVC4.

My best guess is that you still have MVC4 beta or MVC4 RC which haven't been uninstalled - in those versions, the Web API assemblies were GAC-ed.

Uninstall old versions of MVC4 and reinstall MVC4 again. Also, check if the System.Web.Http.dll is set to copy local true.

Comment: Agreed and 1 upped seen this exact thing before

Comment: I removed the vs 11 beta before installing vs 2012. I also removed any mvc 4 beta stuff and ive installed the mvc 4 tools a few times.

Whats even worse is that I went to the dll reference location, loaded it in ILSpy and RouteParameter is there....

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it. It is true that I had left over reminants of the MVC 4 beta on my machine, in the GAC. The dlls were System.Web.Http and System.Web.Http.WebHost. I had to use gacutil /uf to kill them, then once i restarted vs it worked.

Comment: Nope! That last one failed so badly in the end. What I did to fix this was go download the mvc 4 beta installer, install, uninstall then install mvc 4. I guess first time i just installed mvc 4 over the beta and it left all those beta dlls in my gac. Yikes. Thanks guys :)